# SwiftUI - How to get random number within a certain range

Tags: swift, random

I want to bring in a random number within a certain range in getImage method.
(I want 4 random values out of 20 numbers.)

It's hard to explain, so I'll replace it with code.

```
struct LoveBackgroundView: View {
    var itemsPerRow = 4

    func getNumberOfRows() -> Int {
        let heightPerItem = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/CGFloat(self.itemsPerRow)
        return Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.height/heightPerItem) -2

    func getImage(indedxLocation: Int) -> String {
        let getNumber = indexLocation % 20   // value is 0 ~ 19
        let getRandom = getNumber.random(in: 0 ..< 4)  // I want to solve this part

        return String(getRandom)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0 ..< getNumberOfRows()) { i in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.itemsPerRow) { j in
                    Image(self.getImage(indexLocation: (i * self.itemsPerRow) + j))
                    
                    ...
   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is written the way I want it and I want to know the correct logic of this code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple extension for returning multiple random elements:

```
extension Collection {
    func randomElements(count: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element> { shuffled().prefix(count) }
}
```

So you can use it like:

```
(1...50).randomElements(count: 4) // [42, 23, 11, 3]
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain well. I want 4 random values out of 20 numbers. Is there any other way? Thank you.

Comment: What about duplicate numbers? And how do you get those 20 numbers?

Comment: I'll post the full code.

Comment: did you get your answer? @JeeNi

Comment: unfortunately not working... Maybe it wasn't a good approach from the beginning. I will think more and find the answer. Thank you for your help. 